# docker nginx 502 when php using ENTRYPOINT

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have two container are `nginx` and `php-fpm`

```
nginx
  ...
  depends_on:
    - php
php
  ...
```

and `Dockerfile` of `php` container has

```
....
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

`entrypoint.sh` file contain very simple like

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/bash
```

If I remove that line, everything working well, but if I using that, my nginx will not working (502). How to fix that thank

Comment: The `entrypoint.sh` script will be the only thing the container does (and if the base image had a `CMD`, that `ENTRYPOINT` line will reset it).  What's in the script?

Comment: @DavidMaze i Just update on my post

Comment: To repeat this, the `ENTRYPOINT` line is the _only_ thing the container does.  If you're setting that to run a `bash` shell, that runs _instead of_ the PHP server (and, in a Compose context, it will likely exit immediately).  If you're using something like the Docker Hub `php:fpm` image, I'd just delete this `ENTRYPOINT` line and the script, and use the correct default `CMD` from the base image.